# The last word in a string is not reversing

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to reverse the words in a string.

Example,
**Input:*as xsd bf*** would result in **Output:*sa dsx fb***.

My problem is that the last word doesn't reverse.

Example,**Input:*as xsd bf*** would result in **Output:*sa dsx bf***.As you can see bf doesn't get reversed.

My code,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void RevWords(string inp);


int main()
{
     string input;

     cout<<"Enter Sring:"<<endl;
     getline(cin,input);
     cout<<"Entered String:"<<input<<endl;
     RevWords(input);

     return 0;
}

void RevWords(string inp)
{
   int wordEnd=0,indexS=0,indexE=0;
   string newStr;
   newStr=inp;

   while(wordEnd<inp.length())
   {
       if(inp[wordEnd] != ' ')
      {
         wordEnd++;
      }
      else
      { 
         if(inp[wordEnd] == ' ' || inp[wordEnd] == '\0')
         {
             indexE=wordEnd-1;
             while(indexS<wordEnd)
             {
                newStr[indexS]=inp[indexE];
                indexS++;
                indexE--;
             }
             newStr[indexS]=' ';
             indexS++;
         }
         wordEnd++;
       }    
   }
   cout<<newStr<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Try debugging the code, that's the best way to understand what's going on.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is your question, "How do you debug C++ code?" If so, why give us all this code and not tell us what debugger you have?

Comment: Use `std::reverse` on every element of a vector of words, why all this?

Comment: note that `std::string::length` does **not** include the null-terminator, so you're missing your last case

Comment: @LogicStuff Maybe he likes to learn C++ rather than meeting production deadline. People can have other priorities.

Comment: Following LogicStuff's comment: Use a `std::stringstream`, to put the string in a stream, then read individual `std::string`s out of it, and use `std::reverse` to reverse them.

Comment: @Aftnix using the right tool when it is appropriate is part of learning the language

Comment: Well my C++ professor used to forbid us from using shiny library stuff..So i'm kind of biased that way. I think people should learn to do trivial things without library. Guys it's not even a quicksort, its just a reversing ...he'll use the optimized std::reverse when he will write a compiler for MSFT. But right now i guess he should do it without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't handle the last word because you stop before you get there:

```
while(wordEnd<inp.length()) { // When you finally get to the last letter. You will 
                              // exit on the next loop iteration.
   if(inp[wordEnd] != ' ')
```

You need to change it to this:

```
 while(wordEnd<=inp.length()) {
   if(wordEnd < inp.length() && inp[wordEnd] != ' ') {
        //^ This is important so you dont go out of bounds on your string
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/Byqxcd)

Comment: Re: Your Demo : words are fleeting* </grammar nazi>

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I forgot that length doesn't include the null terminator. For that reminder I thank  Ben and BeyelerStudios. And I also thank ben for reminding me of the wordEnd<inp.lenght condition.

Comment: @AndyG This is spelling not grammar </definition nazi> ;) Thanks though i will change it.