# C# version for "The last word in a string is not reversing"

Tags: c#, string

Here is the link to the original problem [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074951/the-last-word-in-a-string-is-not-reversing).Now I was able to solve that problem. But I want to solve the same problem in C#. And I have solved it in one way. But I am facing the same problem when I implement it like in the original link problem.

Here is the code to one of my implementation that solves the problem in C#,

```
using System;

namespace CSharpStrings
{
   class MyStringManipulators
   {
       private string input;
       private string[] subStrs;

       public void GetInputString()
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Enter string:");
          input = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine(ReverseString(input));
       }

       public string ReverseString(string input)
       {
          char[] tempStr = new char[input.Length];
          int tempIndex = 0;

          for(int i=input.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
          {
             tempStr[tempIndex] = input[i];
             tempIndex++;
          }
          String newStr = new String(tempStr);
          //Console.WriteLine(newStr);

          return newStr;
       }

       public string ReverseWordsInStr()
       {
          String newStr="";

          subStrs = input.Split(' ');
          for(int i=0;i<subStrs.Length;i++)
          {
             subStrs[i] = ReverseString(subStrs[i]);
             newStr = newStr + subStrs[i] + " ";
          }
          //Console.WriteLine(newStr);

          return newStr;
      }
  }

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         MyStringManipulators obj = new MyStringManipulators();
         obj.GetInputString();
         Console.WriteLine(obj.ReverseWordsInStr());
      }
   }
}
```

Here is an another version.This version of implementation is actually similar to the one in the link implementation.But,This one has the same problem as in the original link. But, the solution to that problem doesn't work here.As I believe that C# strings are not null terminated.

```
using System;


namespace CSharpStringV2
{
   class MyStringMan
   {
      private string input;

      public void GetInput()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter String:");
         input = Console.ReadLine();
      }

      public void ReverseWords()
      {
         int wordEnd = 0, indexS = 0, indexE = 0;
         char[] newStr=new char[input.Length];

         while (wordEnd < input.Length)
         {
            if (wordEnd<input.Length &&  input[wordEnd] != ' ')
            {
                wordEnd++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (input[wordEnd] == ' ' || wordEnd == input.Length)
                {
                    indexE = wordEnd - 1;
                    while (indexS < wordEnd)
                    {
                        newStr[indexS] = input[indexE];
                        indexS++;
                        indexE--;
                    }
                    newStr[indexS] = ' ';
                    indexS++;
                }
                wordEnd++;
            }
        }
         string nStr = new string(newStr);
         Console.WriteLine(nStr);
    }
 }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStringMan obj = new MyStringMan();
        obj.GetInput();
        obj.ReverseWords();
    }
  }
}
```

And my question is how do i make the second implementation work? I am guessing it has a problem because C# strings don't end with a `\0` terminator.So how do I make the second implementation work,If possible?

Comment: Hint: C# has the [`string.Split(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method which you may find useful. Disclaimer: I've not read your code as there's a lot of it.

Comment: `if (... || wordEnd == input.Length)`  will never be true because of the loop condition: `while (wordEnd < input.Length)`. Try `wordEnd == input.Length - 1`

Comment: How about for a one-liner? `string input = "as xsd bf";
            var output = string.Join(" ", input.Split().Select(x => new string(x.Reverse().ToArray())));`

Comment: @LuckyAli, your first version above works, why are you trying to do it a different way?

Comment: There's also just a lot of inefficient and messy code in your samples, which I think obfuscates the issues you are having. These issues include using a while loops where for loops would be easier and cleaner, writing out your own versions of functions instead of using built in language versions of the same (Reverse and Split in particular), and performing redundant checks (you check wordEnd < input.Length twice in the same code path)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the last word because `wordEnd == input.Length` can never become true due to already exiting the `while (wordEnd < input.Length)`-loop before that.

You need to change that to `while (wordEnd <= input.Length)` just like in the answer you linked.

Edit:
You also need to change the other part to:

```
                if (wordEnd == input.Length || input[wordEnd] == ' ')
                {
                    indexE = wordEnd - 1;
                    while (indexS < wordEnd)
                    {
                        newStr[indexS] = input[indexE];
                        indexS++;
                        indexE--;
                    }
                    if (wordEnd < input.Length)
                    {
                        newStr[indexS] = ' ';
                        indexS++;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: That will lead to index exception when OP tries `input[wordEnd]`.

Comment: Yeah just noticed, thanks. Added the additional changes.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your ReverseWords method to address the issues.

Please see the comments in the code for the changes

```
public void ReverseWords()
{
    int wordEnd = 0, indexS = 0, indexE = 0;
    char[] newStr = new char[input.Length];

    while (wordEnd <= input.Length) //Needed to use <=
    {
        if (wordEnd < input.Length && input[wordEnd] != ' ')
        {
            wordEnd++;
        }
        else
        {
            //Reversed the conditional checks as the second check 
            //is an overflow with the last word
            if (wordEnd == input.Length || input[wordEnd] == ' ')
            {
                indexE = wordEnd - 1;
                while (indexS < wordEnd)
                {
                    newStr[indexS] = input[indexE];
                    indexS++;
                    indexE--;
                }
                //Added condition to not add a space after the last word
                if(wordEnd != input.Length)
                    newStr[indexS] = ' ';
                indexS++;
            }
            wordEnd++;
        }
    }
    string nStr = new string(newStr);
    Console.WriteLine(nStr);
}
```

Comment: It seems like you didn't read his question very carefully because his first chunk of code is basically this (though he doesn't take advantage of Reverse like he should).

Comment: Ah i missed the end where he is simply trying to get the second implementation working.  I can't help but always look for the simplest solution :)

Comment: I agree with you on approaching it in a simpler way, and I'm confused as to why he wants to do it in some other way, but for whatever reason he does. And +1 for your answer since it answers his question most directly